# How do the positive ions in ion thrusters get through the positive grid?

Tags: electrostatics

I'm confused, how could the positive ions get through the positive grid? Because when 2 objects have the same charge, it will be pushed away right?

> [image]

Comment: But does the grid push 'enough'?

Comment: With "small" holes in the grid, the electric field should exist only between the plates, the same way that it does in a parallel plate capacitor.  This means that the positive ions are not repelled until they get between the two plates, which implies that the polarity in the picture is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think that picture you posted is wrong: the grid polarities are reversed. The first grid should be negative to attract  positive ions and second positive to push them away.

The transitional space between first and second grid, where the positive ions must move towards positive grid, I think they make it through there by momentum they previously acquired by being accelerated by the attractive first negative grid. It slows them down but not enough to stop them and as they make it to other side the second positive grid starts pushing them away in desired direction again.